# how to deal with synonymous tags?

Tags: support

As of now, there are 24 questions with the `hp-quality-center` tag and 86 questions with the `hpqc` tag.  Is there a way to merge them or mark them as synonyms?  I prefer the `hp-quality-center` tag, but I don't want to retag the 86 `hpqc` questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So back in 2011, I proposed a synonym. At that time, I was just a regular old user and could only propose synonyms.

It lay dormant for the next four and a half years until some moderator approved it.

It's possible I'm one of the only people in Stack Exchange history to approve their own suggested tag synonym... But it's now approved and it should be taken care of. If it's not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it looks like they're already marked as synonyms of `quality-center`.  See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=master&filter=all.